# A simple looking integration : $\left(\frac{x^3}{1+x^5}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration

One of my friends gave me this problem about a week back and since then, I have been toiling to get a solution to this problem, but I just get stuck at some step. Can someone please tell me the steps to integrate :

$\left(\frac{x^3}{1+x^5}\right)$

If this helps some, [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2F%7B1%2Bx%5E5%7D) gives this answer:

[image]

Comment: you have to do this integration ,with fraction of denominator

Comment: do you mean partial fractions? Okay, I tried that, but got stuck at very first step.

Comment: You have to use partial fractions; the denominator of each piece will be the corresponding root of $x^5+1=0$. Are you sure that a *friend* gave you this gift ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yeah, he was solving $x^4$ in numerator, and gave me this one!

Comment: what kind of friend is this?

Comment: With $x^4$ the answer is immediate ! Ask your *friend* his/her steps with $x^3$ !

Comment: Your friend is very cruel! Let this be a lesson that similar integrands need not lead to similar integrals.

Comment: Are you still concerned by this problem ? What I mean is : do you understand how to go from the smart answer Jack provided to the ugly result from WA ? Let me know.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici no.. but, I am trying to get that answer...

Comment: No to what question ?

Comment: I am unable to get to WA's answer, mainly because Jack's answer (or this question) is above my level..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fraction decomposition is the key. Let $\xi=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{5}\right)$ be a primitive tenth root of unity.

Then $x^5+1 = (x-\xi)(x-\xi^3)(x-\xi^5)(x-\xi^7)(x-\xi^9)$ and:

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{x^3}{1+x^5},x=\xi^{2k+1}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\xi^{10-(2k+1)}\tag{1}$$
so:
$$ \frac{x^3}{1+x^5} = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{k=0}^{4}\frac{\xi^{9-2k}}{x-\xi^{2k+1}}\tag{2}$$
as well as:
$$ \int\frac{x^3}{1+x^5}\,dx = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{k=0}^{4} \xi^{9-2k}\log\left(x-\xi^{2k+1}\right). \tag{3}$$

Comment: Do you mind if I continue from your answer to show how to arrive to the expression given by Wolfram Alpha ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I don't mind at all.

Comment: Thanks... Very nice solution! Please can you explain what does res(a,b) means? Anyways, it's much above my class 12 level!

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

As Dr. Sonnhard Graubner answered,

$$x^5+1=\left( x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{4}-{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}-x+1 \right)$$ Now, all the other roots are complex and then each of them has a conjugate. Playing with them (very funny), you have $$ {x}^{4}-{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}-x+1=\Big(x^2-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) x+1 \Big)\Big(x^2+\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) x+1 \Big)$$ So, you have your three factors for partial fraction decomposition.

Now, have fun and do not forget to thank your *friend* for the gift.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: first of all i would prove that $$-1/5\, \left( x+1 \right) ^{-1}+1/5\,{\frac {{x}^{3}+3\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+1
}{{x}^{4}-{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}-x+1}}
=\frac{x^3}{1+x^5}$$
the partial decomposition
since $$x^5+1=\left( x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{4}-{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}-x+1 \right) $$
the denominator of the second fraction can also be fatorized in to
$$-1/4\, \left( x\sqrt {5}+2\,{x}^{2}-x+2 \right)  \left( x\sqrt {5}-2\,
{x}^{2}+x-2 \right) 
$$

Comment: And so what? How do you arrive at the closed form given by the OP?

Comment: this is not so simple the first integral is easy but the denominator in the second fraction must be factorized one moment please